# How to (cleanly) dismount sshfs when mounted on a NFS mount point?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, nfs, sshfs

My coworker has a desktop computer with `/home` shared on our file server. I have developed a Perl script for `sshfs`-mounting a certain directory on another SSH host which works fine on my laptop.

On his computer the script fails to dismount the `sshfs` at the end and leaves the mountpoint unclean. I didn't find any way to recover the mountpoint other than rebooting. After some testing I found that the difference between our setups is that his `/home` is on NFS. In his `/tmp` it works flawlessly.

After mount, during script operation everything is fine. But when killing the `sshfs` process it is listed as `<defunc>` by `ps` until the parent process (the Perl script) exits. When running a raw `sshfs` command on the shell the problem still occurs.

A `ls -dl` output for the mountpoint looks like this (as remembered - I have no real copy of the shell output at hand):

```
? 1 ? ? 4096 Feb  9 15:37 file_archive/
```

(only question marks for most information, at least all permission details)

The sshfs mount is still listed by `mount` but an unmount operation fails with error *permission denied* even when doing as `root`.

I searched Google but only found lots of comparisons between sshfs and NFS for running network filesystems. How can I do a sshfs mount/unmount in NFS directory safely?

Answer (score 47):

You should be able to unmount the sshfs share by executing:

```
 fusermount -u /path/to/sshfs/share
```

Comment: I tried this but got *permission denied*. Of course an ordinary `umount` must fail when run as non-root user.

Comment: Most likely the reason you can't unmount (with any method) is because his home dir is mount from NFS where it's exported with the `root_squash` option.  Thus, root has no authority in his home dir.  You might turn off `root_squash` but it's probably safer to just mount somewhere else.

Comment: I forget everytime, that `umount` or `fusermount -u` doesnt work, when the directory is used somewhere. So `cd` out of the directory before using `fusermount -u` or use `lsof /my/local/mountpoint`

Comment: Returns an error message: "fuse: bad mount point `/path/to/sshfs/share': Input/output error"

Answer (score 18):

Just kill the process using pkill to and then un mount the mounted folder path.

```
 pkill -kill -f "sshfs" && umount /path/to/sshfs/share
```

Comment: Sometimes I have to do "sudo umount -f" or "sudo umount -l" instead of umount.

Comment: This returns the following error message: "umount: /path/to/sshfs/share: Transport endpoint is not connected"

Answer (score 3):

This post is rather old.  Currently on RHEL8, this is all that is required.  There is no need to kill sshfs processes:

`sudo umount <mountpoint>`

Answer (score 0):

This answer refers to Ubuntu 20.04, but in general you need two steps to properly unmount a `sshfs` volume: i) kill the `sshfs` process and ii) use `sudo` to unmount. Without using `sudo`, the system reports messages like "Device or resource busy" or "Transport endpoint is not connected", even if permissions are correct.

The instructions look like:

```
killall sshfs
sudo umount -l /path/to/sshfs/share
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo diskutil umount force ~/mount/
```

Seems like this command works in OS X.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain what this code does and how it addresses the problem?  Unexplained code is [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because it doesn't teach the solution.  Thanks.  [from review queue](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/498566)

Comment: This is for OS X. The question asked for Linux.